# Tags on comments/ assigning tags by others

Tags: discussion

The system is designed to allow intentional tagging of questions, by the author.

I find that I often want to qualify an upvote or downvote in an answer.

For example, when I answer I'd like to point out how I'm answering for example, to say that I am an American English native speaker, or I claim special technical knowledge, or that my answer is speculative or from personal feeling as opposed to a systematic corpus search or quote from an off-line reference. And just like tags for questions, these things may already be mentioned -in- the answer textually as key words, but having a tag makes it easier to categorize and search. This could also make it more likely that an explanation for a downvote gets made (tags like 'I like this' (i.e. correctness may not be the primary reason for upvoting), or 'irrelevant' or 'coinage' or 'self-reporting' or 'AustE'.

This could be implemented just like tags for questions.

What would be the consequences of this?

What do you think?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking for a way to mark upvotes/downvotes as a particular _type_ of vote (a la the tagging system)?

Comment: Well, yes, maybe have a list of tags to choose from (or add one) when up/down voting, in addition to tagging your own answers.

Comment: Sounds like excessive detail to me. You can already set out your own 'credentials' on your *info* page, and most people don't even do much of that anyway. If you downvote, good manners implies you should at least say why, and most people tend to do that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: as to credentials, my question is not about the person it is about tags for a particular question. As to good manners on downvoting, I don't know what you're looking at but I don't think I've ever seen an explanation of a downvote. Ah... sorry...once I did.

Comment: Okay, you got me! I knew my *most people tend to do that* wasn't really true - it was just tongue-in-cheek. But since I do believe the rest of the sentence, I slyly hoped to shame some others into explaining themselves a bit more. As for the rest, I guess we just agree to differ; I stand by my *first* sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The up-votes and down-votes for a question are already qualified.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

You are asking for being able to associate a reason to the votes you cast.
What would change if users would be able to associate a reason to their votes? Would a different reason cause a different reputation change? Would it cause the question to be differently ordered in the list of questions?
If the different reason for voting doesn't have any effect on the vote itself, or how the question is rendered, then I guess that such feature will not be implemented.

The other question is then: Is it really worth the time took to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can always leave a comment if you wish to elaborate on why you upvoted or downvoted a post.